# How can I merge two directories using opendiff?

Tags: merge, directory

This should be simple, right? I want to compare two directories, foo and bar. I want to cherrypick changes in foo and place them in bar. If I run

```
opendiff foo bar -merge bar
```

to specify bar as the merge directory, nothing happens when I "save merge" on my individual files. If I don't specify a merge and select bar as my merge directory from the save dialog, it gives me an error.

Surely I'm missing something?

Answer (score -1):

Here's documentation on opendiff:

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/opendiff/